# How to prevent access to a specific directory?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, apache2, php

I am storing images on `/var/www/html/assets/photos/` and I don't want users to be able to navigate via browser or any other way to this folder. I want only my PHP scripts to be able to use this folder.

How to do that?

Comment: How about setting permissions?

Comment: Thank you! I am quite new to this. Is it done via the `.htaccess` file, or through the apache2 config file, or something else?

Comment: Having your photos below `html` and then fiddling around with permissions or `.htaccess` rules is not the way to go. Simply don't put photos below `/html/`, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Permissions is a bad idea, because `php` might run with the same user as the webserver, so it won't work to give `php` access and deny access to the webserver.

Comment: I didn't put photos below `/html/`.. or you meant PUT and accidentally wrote "don't"?

Comment: @FreiKhost what pLumo means is that, if your DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html/` and you don't want those photos to be accessible from the browser, let your PHP scripts manage those photos anywhere outside of that directory and its subdirectories. For example, store them in `/var/www/photos/`. (you can have a better structure most likely, but this is an example)

Answer (score 2):

Open the folder with your favorite FTP client - unless you're local and can just navigate to the folder.

Add a file called `.htaccess`. The '.' is important and mandatory.

Edit the .htaccess file with a plain-text editor (don't use a word-processor application) and add the following line:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Save the file.

What this will do is prevent indexing the files in the folder. If people try to access the folder directly, they'll get a 403 forbidden error.

At the same time, you can still link directly to files in that folder.

So, let's say you added the .htaccess to a directory called /tmp. You can still link to, use, and send people to /tmp/picture.jpg like normal, but people won't be able to browse the directory and find files you don't want them to see.

For more information, [click this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/DirectoryListings).

Comment: Just nitpicking here but the claim `The permissions for .htaccess should be 644.` is not true. As long as Apache has read access, that's enough. For example, if the file owner is `www-data` then `400` (or its equivalent `r--------`) is enough to make it work.

Comment: @Dan Hey, neat! You're right! I learned something new, thanks!